# Is it possible to distribute an OSX app ad-hoc without UUID but with entitlements

Tags: xcode, macos, keychain, provisioning-profile, nevpnmanager

I'm having some serious trouble signing an application for ad-hoc distribution. Is it possible to distribute an app with the following requirements?:

1. Does not require tester to provide UUID up front
2. Outside app store
3. Utilizes entitlements such as VPN or Keychain Sharing

I ask because exporting without signing (Organizer (select archive) > Export > Export as Mac Application) fails with "embedded provisioning profile not valid: ..." on some devices.  It appears to work on others though.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to use the NetworkExtension framework (which I'm assuming because you tagged your question with nevpnmanager,) unfortunately that's only available in App Store apps.

I know this because I asked Apple. I was trying to make a non App Store NEVPN app, but no dice. Quinn from Developer Tech Support told me the NEVPN stuff is only available for App Store apps, and that I should file a bug report (which I think I did.)

Comment: Thank you.  Any way you could track down the bug report?  Would like to toss in my support for an update.